# Is it possible to return something or nothing?

Tags: rust

Is it possible in Rust to make a function return either an object or nothing according to a condition defined within it?

For example:

```
fn login(self, username: Username, password: Password) -> Calculator_1 {
        let ch = match self.ch.send(username.to_string()).send(password.to_string()).offer() {
            Left(ch) => ch,
            Right(ch) => { ch.close(); return }
        };
        Calculator_1::new(ch)
    }
```

I'm using the session-types library in Rust, so I want the object to be returned only if the username and password are verified, which should go to the `Left` arm. If it's not verified, then it should go to the `Right` arm and close the program. I cannot really get this to work in terms of returning or not returning something.

Comment: This question might be downvoted and/or closed: you are asking about a very fundamental feature of Rust, namely the `Option<T>` type. However, I couldn't find a question like this on SO, so it's not a duplicate (to my knowledge). So this question might be valid and worth answering. Then, however, you provided way too much (irrelevant) information. So you should simplify your example a whole lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Option<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html). An `Option<T>` can either hold `Some(T)` (some value of type `T`, where `T` is a generic type parameter) or `None` (no value).

```
fn login(self, username: Username, password: Password) -> Option<Calculator_1> {
    match self.ch.send(username.to_string()).send(password.to_string()).offer() {
        Left(ch) => Some(Calculator_1::new(ch)),
        Right(ch) => { ch.close(); None }
    }        
}
```

For more information, read the [*Error Handling*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/error-handling.html) chapter in *The Rust Programming Language*.

Comment: thanks for answering. however why I still get this error. bear with me pls as Im just newbie in Rust no method named `add` found for type `std::option::Option<Calculator_1>

Comment: @Omar How do you "add" using something that might be not present? Did you read [the suggested chapter of the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/error-handling.html#composing-optiont-values)? You may also want to [read up on enums](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/enums.html).

Comment: Well my basic understanding is that the Option will either return Calculator_1 or wont return anything. if it returns Calculator_1, I have defined a method called add in it. So I thought I can just directly access it ..

Comment: I have got it to work :) ,, thanks ... matched my result in enum :)